# The app.locals is coming as undefined in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am setting the app.locals in server.js here is my code

```
 //server.js
 app.locals.abi=abi;
 app.locals.SampleContract=SampleContract;
 app.locals.web3=web3;
```

But when I am calling the same from another file, app.locals is coming as undefined.

```
function getDetails(req,res,next){
    contract=req.locals.SampleContract;
    web3=req.locals.web3;
    contractAddress=req.locals.contractAddress;
    next();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `req.app.locals` not `req.locals`

Answer (score 0):

set as key value pair

```
app.set('abi',abi);
app.set('SampleContract',SampleContract);
app.set('web3',web3);
```

get using key

```
function getDetails(req,res,next){
    contract=req.app.get('SampleContract');
    web3=req.locals.web3;
    contractAddress=req.locals.contractAddress;
    next();
}
```

Comment: if you get the answer let me know

Comment: can you console your req?

Comment: The value is coming as undefined

Comment: Yes, it' coming as undefined

Comment: i think the problem is in your router part.

Comment: you are not calling the router perfectlly

Comment: How will I define app.locals in Server.js and call it in controller

Comment: post your router part. you are not calling your router correctlly